# Correct datatype for dynamic data?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

I'm writing a parser for Articy Draft, a writing tool which exports an entire project as an XML document. Most of it is fairly straightforward, but the way it handles entities is a little tricky.

Essentially, each entity has a collection of features, each of which is a collection of properties. Each property can be either an int, a string or an enumeration and has a name (string) and an ID (long).

I'm trying to figure out the best way of storing this data in each entity. I'd like it to be generic, rather than have predefined entities, as that is more future-proof. I guess I'm too inexperienced with C# to know of a correct way to store it. I only really *need* to index based on the name of the data field. Being able to index on the ID as well would be a bonus, but not at all necessary.

I could have three dictionaries, one each for int, enumeration and string. Index each one based on either the name or the index, whichever I prefer. It seems a bit messy having three different collections, but maybe that's the best way.

I could use DataColumns to create a DataTable in each entity with columns for ID, name, datatype and value, but then you'd need three value columns (or two, I guess since enumeration could be stored as an int) and that's a bit messy too.

It's a problem I can easily solve with my current knowledge, but it just feels like there's a more elegant solution than I'm aware of and there is the opportunity for me to expand my C# knowledge a little bit here.

Comment: Try to make sure that there is a actual, well defined question being asked, and more people will respond/answer your question.  Here, you could ask, "What would be the simplest (or best, or nicest, or most elegant) method I could use?"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing some reading into the C# ExpandoObject which I believe will provide a good solution for you

[C# ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)